# Website URL Permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I used Prophoto 4 and recently upgraded my site to Profoto 7 and moved to a new Profoto template.
My website URL is www.lorrainebhandariphoto-video.co.uk
Now my site address URL and wordpress address URL is www.lorrainebhandariphoto-video.co.uk/blog
I am not technical. Some of the permalinks of new pages I created require to be changed also. 
What do I need to do? I'm with JustHost.

Comment: Sorry I should say I don't want it to show blog and for example the Get In Touch permalink shows as https://www.lorrainebhandariphoto-video.co.uk/blog/#goto-39400d7b-bbbe-47ce-9f37-c0ef0624b643

Comment: need an access to solve your issue